# Change background music volume from activity to service

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-music

I'm new to android, and working on a project where I have to implement background music in our app. I've already implemented background music using service, the problem is: I don't know how to change the volume of the music dynamically using a seekbar from an activity.

My service looks like this:

```
package hu.szoftverprojekt.holdemfree.controller;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import hu.szoftverprojekt.holdemfree.R;

public class PlaySound extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ss);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        player.setVolume(SettingsScreen.volume, SettingsScreen.volume);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well once you have the `SeekBar` and the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` being called as you change the `SeekBar`, the next major thing is communicating this from your activity to your service this change.

Have a look at the android docs [Creating a bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Creating) for the offical way to communicate between an `Activity` and `Service` using no 3rd party libraries.

**HOWEVER**

You could also use a 3rd party library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (which I'd recommend as it's much easier to use and implement in my opinion).

Here is an example using `EventBus`:

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
}
```

**MediaVolumeEvent.java:**

```
public class MediaVolumeEvent {
    private int volume;

    public MediaVolumeEvent(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

**PlaySound.java:**

```
public class PlaySound extends Service {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    player.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN) 
  public void onEvent(MediaVolumeEvent event){
    player.setVolume(event.getVolume(), event.getVolume());
  }
}
```

In your activity inside the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
SeekBar seekBar= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new MediaVolumeEvent(progress));
    }       
});
```

Comment: Please see my update, I forgot to add the `@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN) ` on the `onEvent` method in the service class which is needed for the service to actually get the message sent by the activity

Comment: Thank you very much! :) You helped me a lot!

Comment: Sure thing. Please do mark this question as solved if it is. Thank you